# Determining the entropy of a string if each character has a slight bias

Tags: random, entropy

Let's say I need to generate a 32-character secret comprised of ASCII characters from the set '0'..'9'.  Here's one way of doing it:

```
VALID_CHARS = '0123456789'

generate_secret_string() {
    random = get_crypto_random_bytes(32)
    secret = ''
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        secret += VALID_CHARS[random[i] % 10]
    }
    return secret
}
```

My concern is that my character selection is biased.  Because 10 doesn't divide evenly into 256, the first 6 VALID_CHARS are slightly more likely to occur.

The secret space is 10<sup>32</sup>, but my generated secrets have less entropy than that.  How can I calculate precisely how much entropy I actually have?

**Update**: Clarifications

- For this question, I just want to know how to compute the entropy of this technique.  I'm trying to compare it against other techniques for which I know how to compute the entropy.
- The parameter I chose here (10 valid chars) is just an example.  I'd like to be able to evaluate the entropy for other character ranges as well.

Comment: This depends entirely on the kind of bias. If you have `mod 256` and have 255 characters, then the first character is twice as likely to appear. If you have 170 characters `mod 170`, then the first 85 characters would be twice as likely. I am not really a math person, so I can't answer precisely, but I know that bias can be more and less severe.

Comment: At the point you're doing this, I'd probably just seed a normal random number generator with the crypto-random value, then just generate unbiased digits, eg `int nextDigit = random.Next(0, 10);`  In most base language utilities, the problem with random generators is doing something like seeding off the system time, as opposed to a material weakness in the PRNG itself.  There are also usually better libraries to help you out with this, anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[For reasons that are a bit involved](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67408/33557), cryptographers use the [min-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-entropy) of a distribution as a measure of its strength:

> The **min-entropy**, in information theory, is the smallest of the Rényi family of entropies, corresponding to the most conservative way of measuring the unpredictability of a set of outcomes, as the negative logarithm of the probability of the *most likely* outcome.

One neat things about min-entropy is that it's easier to compute than the Shannon entropy (a.k.a. the average entropy) that hft's answer has amply illustrated (which requires you to compute the entropy of all alternatives and do a weighted average by their probabilities).  You just have to:

1. Figure out the probability of the *likeliest* outcome.  In this case, it's 26/256 ≈ 10.16%.
2. Take the negative logarithm of that: -log<sub>2</sub>(25/256) ≈ 3.30 bits.

This means any digit chosen by your procedure will have **at least** 3.30 bits of entropy, and possibly more.  By comparison, the entropy of a uniformly chosen decimal digit is log<sub>2</sub>(10) ≈ 3.32 bits.  Since the min-entropy you're getting only marginally lower than the entropy of a uniform random digit (which is the best case you could hope for), we can conclude that the digit selection bias in your example doesn't matter in practice.

Comment: Thanks!  I had a follow-up that I decided to post as a separate question: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/210895/163855

Answer (score 5):

> My concern is that my character selection is biased. Because 10 doesn't divide evenly into 256, the first 6 VALID_CHARS are slightly more likely to occur.
>
> The secret space is 10^32, but my generated secrets have less entropy than that. How can I calculate precisely how much entropy I actually have?

Because not every digit is equally likely you can not set

```
p(i) = 1/10
```

for all the digits.

Rather, you have

```
p(0) = p(1) = ... = p(5) = 26/256
```

and

```
p(6)=...=p(9) = 25/256
```

So, use the usual formula for entropy:

```
e = -Sum[ p(i) log(p(i)) ] = -6*(26/256)*(log2(26/256))-4*(25/256)*(log2(25/256)) = 3.32166...
```

to get the numerical value of "entropy" e for one digit (n.b., if p(i) were 1/10 for each digit then this would be e=log(10), but it is not)

Then the entropy for the full string of 32 characters is:

```
32*e = 106.293...
```

Comment: I've forgotten how to format math on this stackexchange...

Comment: oh no, there is actually no LaTex engine! Let me try to reformat this answer some other way I guess...

Comment: yep, crypto stack exchange has MathJax, but infosec does not. https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/70830

Comment: *weeping emoji*

Comment: The average entropy formula given is right, but you don't give the answer: e = 3.3217 bits, and therefore 32 × e = 106.29 bits. Note that log2(10) = 3.3219 and thus 32 × log2(10) = 106.30 bits. If we [use a min-entropy calculation instead](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66097/why-is-min-entropy-significant-in-cryptography) then we get -log2(26/256) = 3.2996 bits, and 32 × -log2(26/256) = 105.59 bits. Which means that the bias in this example is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks, I added some of the actual numerical values to the answer to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You need `log2(10^32)` entropy. By my calculation, 106.3 bits. What if you do `get_crypto_random_bytes(14)`, throw away 6 bits, and then treat the value as a single number and convert it to decimal?

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that 0,1,2,3,4,5 are more likely than 6,7,8,9

Comment: My proposed alternative algorithm does not have this problem.

Comment: Then this is not an answer to the question...

Comment: I interpreted the question to be "how to do this better". If the question really only concerns "analyze this less good method", then I did not answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, in this case I actually just want to analyze this one method.  (So I can compare it against other methods that I already know how to analyze.)